# How to reload collection view inside UICollectionReusableView in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

1. I have a UICollectionView (let name aCollection) inside a View controller and i use a UICollectionReusableView to show header at the top of collection view

   [image]
2. I also have a another UICollectionView (let name bCollection) in UICollectionReusableView. I need to show here top user list. but when i am trying to connect an outlet from storyboard i am getting an error

   [image]
3. I know how to reload data in collection view

   `self.aCollection.reloadData()`
4. My issue is how to connect bCollection outlet and how to reload bCollection to show user list coming from web services?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To take the outlet of `bCollection`, you need to create a subclass of `UICollectionReusableView`.

**Example:**

**`UIViewController` containing `aCollection`:**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource
{
    @IBOutlet weak var aCollectionView: UICollectionView!

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return 10
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
    {
        return collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "aCell", for: indexPath)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView
    {
        return (collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "reusableView", for: indexPath) as! ReusableView)
    }
}
```

**`UICollectionReusableView` containing `bCollection`:**

```
class ReusableView: UICollectionReusableView, UICollectionViewDataSource
{
    @IBOutlet weak var bCollectionView: UICollectionView!

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return 10
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
    {
        return collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "bCell", for: indexPath)
    }
}
```

**Interface Screenshot**

[image]

**Edit:**

To reload `bCollection`:

You need a reference to the `reusableView` that you are using. The way you are using it `ReusableView()` is not right.

Use it like this:

```
var reusableView: ReusableView?

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView
{
    self.reusableView = (collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "reusableView", for: indexPath) as! ReusableView) //Storing the reference to reusableView
    return self.reusableView!
}
```

Now, to reload `bCollection`,

```
    self.reusableView?.bCollectionView.reloadData()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer !
I will check it and accept if it works

Comment: Sure..:) Let me know if you face any issues.

Comment: when am trying to reload bCollection view its giving an error 
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
my approach to reload : `ReusableView().bCollectionView.reloadData()`

Comment: inside UIViewController. after getting response from API

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151601/discussion-between-museer-ansari-and-pgdev).

Answer (score 0):

Since your `UICollectionView`  (`bCollection`) is inside the `UICollectionReusableView` you can connect outlet to `UICollectionReusableView`'s class only. So I believe you may have to create a custom class for `UICollectionReusableView` and assign it in the storyboard and connect `bCollection` 's outlet to that custom class

Comment: Hi, i did same this as you mention but its not working

Comment: @MuseerAnsari I just tried the same way and I was able to connect the outlet to UICollectionReusableView's custom class